# wsimport forgets one proxy class

Tags: java, web-services, proxy-classes, wsimport

I use *wsimport* to generate the proxy classes from the WSDL file. Class A gets generated, but the class B which corresponds to the A's parameter for its constructor - not.
What could be the reason for that? Thx.

Here is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01-. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01-. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://project-project.org/ref" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://project-project.org/ref" name="MyName">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" schemaLocation="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName?xsd=1" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://project-project.org/ref/tools" schemaLocation="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName?xsd=2" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://project-project.org/ref/datatypes" schemaLocation="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName?xsd=3" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://project-project.org/ref/ProjectService" schemaLocation="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName?xsd=4" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://project-project.org/ref/MyName" schemaLocation="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName?xsd=5" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://project-project.org/ref" schemaLocation="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName?xsd=6" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://project-project.org/objects" schemaLocation="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName?xsd=7" />
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="MyName">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:MyName" />
</message>
<message name="MyNameResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:MyNameResponse" />
</message>
<message name="ProjectServicePull">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:ProjectServicePull" />
</message>
<message name="ProjectServicePullResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:ProjectServicePullResponse" />
</message>
<portType name="MyName">
<operation name="MyName">
<input message="tns:MyName" />
<output message="tns:MyNameResponse" />
</operation>
<operation name="ProjectServicePull">
<input message="tns:ProjectServicePull" />
<output message="tns:ProjectServicePullResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="MyNamePortBinding" type="tns:MyName">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
<operation name="MyName">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://project-project.org/ref/MyName" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="ProjectServicePull">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://project-project.org/ref/ProjectService/Pull" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="MyName">
<port name="MyNamePort" binding="tns:MyNamePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://X.X.X.X:8080/myName/MyName" />
</port>
</service>
```

Comment: You have to get more specific. There is no such thing as a constructor in a WSDL so the generated Java classes can't have one that's different from the default constructor either. Do you use JAX-WS to generate the WSDL? Could you extract or create a WSDL snippet that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
"so the generated Java classes can't have one that's different from the default constructor" That's a bit of a problem. What can I do to make it import other constructors and their dependencies in form of other classes? PS. I see, I'll post the wsdl a bit later today.

Comment: This doesn't help. They types are contained in the linked schema files. Still, this doesn't change anything. You can't create a specific constructor with *wsimport*. XML Schema is solely about data.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. What is usually done in cases like mine?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155361/what-jaxb-needs-a-public-no-arg-constructor-for In your case the only option is refactoring your code and creating non-arg constructor to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your schemas are incomplete for class B and therefore jaxb cannot successfully create the class.  if i understand you correctly, you are saying that the generated class A *will not compile* after generation due to missing classes?  does wsimport spit out any warnings?

Comment: No warnings. It creates the proxy class A but with a default constructor. There is no constructor created which accepts parameters though it exists on the server side in code. I need it and whatever it depends on.

Comment: @azerIO - are you trying to create a webservice client or server?

Comment: @azerIO - i just wanted to make sure, because your comments were confusing.  what the classes look like on the server have no bearing on what the client artifacts will look like.