# Collection is empty when returning from JAX-RS/CXF service

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I have a service method defined as:

```
public JaxbList<Deal> getDeal() {
    List<Deal> deals = new ArrayList<Deal>();
    Deal type = new Deal();
    type.setDealID(1);
    type.setName("June Discounts");
    deals.add(type);
    JaxbList list = new JaxbList(deals);
    System.out.println("List size -> " + list.getList().size());
    return list;
}
```

My client is defined as:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("....");
    JaxbList deals = client.path("exampleservice/getDeal")
        .accept("application/xml").get(JaxbList.class);

    List<Deal> types = deals.getList();
```

When I print out the size of the collection in the service method, the result comes back as 1.  But, the size of my 'types' list from the client is 0.  When I open in a browser, the 1 deal is displayed.  So, this issue seems to be my client.  I'm not sure where though.

Ideas?

Here is my JaxbList class:

```
public class JaxbList<T>{
    protected List<T> list;

    public JaxbList(){}

    public JaxbList(List<T> list){
        System.out.println("Setting list...");
        this.list=list;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Item")
    public List<T> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't there a setter for the field `list` ?

Comment: Great work KasunBG.  Not sure why results were able to be returned in the browser, but after adding the setter, it's working fine.  Simple/Stupid mistake on my part.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know this was the actual reason. I should have put this as an answer rather than a comment to earn some reputation! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by KasunBG your `public JaxbList(List<T> list)` constructor is never called by JAXB. The default no-arg one is used instead (see some discussion  at [What JAXB needs a public no-arg constructor for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155361/what-jaxb-needs-a-public-no-arg-constructor-for)). Actually Java compiler should complain about this situation with two constructors and "never initialized field `list`".

The solution is to introduce a `setList()` setter and throw a runtime exception from a no-arg constructor.