# Why is a default constructor required for objects exported by a JAX-WS?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-ws, jax-ws-customization

JAX-WS requires that all classes that are transmitted have a default contructor (no-arg constructor). I do not understand that requirement because clients create their own classes based on the WSDL. IMO this requirement makes sense only for those classes that are used as input parameters of the Webservice.

Does anyone know how to circumvent that requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use *JAX-WS* you are using a *JAXB* implementation to serialize your java objects to *XML*.

**So, the 'problem' is how JAXB works.**

To use *JAXB*, you need to create a *JAXBContext* passing it all the classes that can be marshaled/unmarshaled. When creating the context, *JAXB* will check that all the given classes have a no-arg constructor. If at least one of those classes does not have this kind of constructor, the context will not be created.

Why *JAXB* do this? It needs this no-arg constructor ONLY when transforming from XML to Object (unmarshalling), but the issue is when you are creating the context, JAXB does not know what you want to do (marshal or unmarshal)!

*Conclusion:* JAXB will accept only classes that it can marshal AND unmarshal. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155361/what-jaxb-needs-a-public-no-arg-constructor-for)

**Knowing this, what happen in JAX-WS?**

When you declare a `@WebMethod` the *parameters* and *return value* classes will be added to a JAXB context. And is because of this that all the classes related to a web service input and output needs a no-arg constructor.

*Conclusion:* is JAXB fault ;-)

**But what if I need to use a class that does not have a no-arg constructor?**

You can use an *XMLAdapter*! Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387296/jaxb-and-constructors) for more info ...

Comment: So the problem seems to be that JAXB does not distinguish between classes it has to marshalling or unmarshal. If this feature was supported then JAX-WS could build a corresponding JAXBContext. I think that would make a nice feature request for a coming JAXB specification.

Comment: I strongly agree with you. Actually the guys from MOXy (A JAXB implementation by EclipseLink) have an open ticket to add multi-args constructors support:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328951

Answer (score -2):

> Does anyone know how to circumvent that requirement?

Yes - rewrite JAX-WS.

It's probably using a default ctor and reflection to populate objects, because it can't easily know about every possible ctor that someone like you might write.

This is a drawback of using someone else's framework: you have to play by their rules.

> clients create their own classes based on the WSDL

I thought that's what the library helped clients do.  You didn't write the code to parse and interpret the WSDL, did you?

Comment: The objects must not be populated by JAX-WS on the server side. JAX-WS transmits them only.