# Java XML - "1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions"

Tags: java, xml

I am runing this code in my Java app and the first line throws an exception **IllegalAnnotationExceptions** :

```java
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
// output pretty printed
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);                         
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(productFound, serverOutput);
```

I'm not familiar with XML format. So, from what I've seen on the internet, the problem comes from the class Product, which means this file :

```java
package service;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)


public class Product {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "price")
    private String price;


    public Product(String id, String name, String price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Especially regarding the annotations.
Did I do something wrong ? Or does something look weird in my code ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Product class must have a no-arg constructor. For Java classes with no
constructor, the Java compiler synthesises a no-arg one for the class. Once you explicitly add a constructor, no default no-arg constructor is added by the compiler, hence here you must also add an explicit no-arg constructor for the implementation of JAXB to use.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. Now I fixed it and it works, thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the JAXB implementation that you are using, you might need to add a no-argument constructor to your `Product` class, e.g.:

```
public Product() {}
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155361/what-jaxb-needs-a-public-no-arg-constructor-for) for further information.